# How I can disable many specific dates in Melt UI calendar?

Tags: calendar, svelte, sveltekit

I have this property for Melt Calendar:

```js
const {
  elements: { calendar, heading, grid, cell, prevButton, nextButton },
  states: { months, headingValue, weekdays },
  helpers: { isDateDisabled, isDateUnavailable }
} = createCalendar({
  defaultValue: new CalendarDate(year, month, day),
  locale: 'ph',
  fixedWeeks: true,
  isDateUnavailable: (date) => {
    return isWeekend(date, 'en')
  }
});
```

I can also disable specific date by using:

```js
isDateDisabled: (date) => {
  return date.day == 1
}
```

But I can only do this once.

I want to disable more dates that are in array form, for example:
Holidays = [12/25, ...]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use array or set functions.
Sets are more efficient but it probably would not matter too much.

E.g.

```js
const holidays = new Set(['12/25', ...]);
...
isDateDisabled: (date) => {
  return holidays.has(date.month + '/' + date.day);
}
```